# Confirmation link in email has been sent, but how do I test the link?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, email

I have an MVC (C#) application where I'm in the middle of testing confirmation email loops. When someone registers on my application, an email is sent to me so I can approve their account. My application successfully sends the email to me with a link, when I click the link in the email it also successfully sends an email to the registrant that I have approved their account. What I can't see is the actual confirmation page that should come up when I click the link in the email, I get a "Site can't be reached" error. How do you test these types of loops with an unpublished project?

The code that formats the link sent to me:

```
"Body = <h1>New User: " + model.Email.ToString() + "</h1><p><a href=\"" + Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + "/Account/ConfirmRegistration?id=" + user.Id.ToString() + "\" >Confirm Registration</a></p>"
```

The resulting link looks similar to this https://localhost/Account/ConfirmRegistration?id=guid-goes-here. Seems all I would need to do is add a port number on the end of localhost but I'm unsure what that number would be. 80 and 443 don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `Request.Url.Host`. If the host and port are `http + 80` or `https + 443`, you don't need to include them.

I would recommend you manually specify the host in `appsettings.json`, rather than trying to work it out at runtime. There are scenarios where you can have multiple domain names pointing to the same site (`www.foo.com`, `foo.com`, `rebrandedfoo.com`), and you prefer users to use one of the domains over the other. There are also other parts of a website that usually need the hostname specified, e.g. generating a jwt for authentication.